# The old QWidget::event() return value question?

Tags: qt, qt5, qevent

Long years past a user asked [this](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/58984-QWidget-event()-return-value-question) question on the Qt centre forum and it was left unanswered. It is still relevant, in particular in relation to  `QWheelEvent`. In my experience, the `QWheelEvent` must be either `accept()`ed or `ignore()`d by an event handler, but mouse events can return `true` and it counts as an `accept()`? What have you learned in relation to the `QEvent::event()` return value? Obviously, a returned `true` does not always count as `accept()` and the documentation is vague, at best.